# Which method to read yaml file and have the same return of the read method of ini?

Tags: python, yaml, ini

I'm working on a project I want to change the .ini configuration file to .yaml. In a function I have return before read .ini file and now I want it to have the same return type but to the .yaml file. How do I do this?
Could someone explain to me what kind of return this is?

- To .yaml file

  ```
  stream = file('file.yaml', 'r')    
  return yaml.load(stream) ????
  return yaml.dump(stream) ???? ????
  ```
- To .ini file

  ```
  config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()    
  config.read('file.ini')
  return config
  ```

If I print `config`, I have this:

```
ConfigParser.ConfigParser instance at 0x000000000124FE08
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no single operation that will give you a single `dict` representing the contents of the `ini` file. You have to build it yourself. `ConfigParser.sections` and `ConfigParser.items` should make it fairly straightforward. Once you have that, you can use `yaml.dump`.

Comment: In Python 3, a `ConfigParser` instance *does* have a mapping interface, so `yaml.dump(c)` would work, but the resulting YAML is ridiculously verbose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do `config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()`, it is for sure
the `config` is a `ConfigParser` instance. That has all kinds of special methods and the rest 
of your program will assume to be able to call.

If you don't want to change the rest of your program, you should set up your YAML config file
with at the root a mapping for which the keys are the section names in your INI file, 
and the values are again mapping representing the key-value pairs of each section:

```
section1:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

section2:
  key1: value3
  key3: value4
```

Then you load that YAML file and convert the resulting data structure to a ConfigParser instance
which you can then use as a ConfigParser read from an INI file:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from configparser import ConfigParser


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
with open('file.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.load(stream)

config = ConfigParser()
config.read_dict(data)
config.write(sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
[section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[section2]
key1 = value3
key3 = value4
```

So `config` (assuming your `file.yaml` makes sense), can be passed to the rest of the program.

Please note:

- `config.write()` is only there to show the result is a `ConfigParser` instance, 
  in the final program you don't need that.
- Your YAML loading example doesn't close the input stream, that is not good practise. Use the `with` statement or pass a `pathlib.Path` to `yaml.load`:

  ```
  from pathlib import Path
  file_name = Path('file.yaml')
  yaml.load(file_name)
  ```
- It is possible to directly load into `ConfigParser` instance by
  tagging the root level mapping in your YAML file and providing the
  appropriate tag processing, but I don't think that is worth it. Your
  time would be better spent changing the rest of the program from
  assuming sections to dealing with `data` (a two level dictionary
  structure) directly.

Comment: What is or does this part: yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe') ?

Comment: If I need to take de sections and use: "print(config.sections())". I have the return: " [u'OUTRO', u'MAIN'] ". Why I have this 'u'??????

Comment: You load unicode from a YAML file. Are you still on python 2.7 (it will end-of-life in 2020)?

Comment: Yes, I use python 2.7 yet. And how do I solve this "u"?

Comment: There is nothing to solve, this is the correct output. 1) Upgrade to Python 3.7, do you want to wait until it is no longer supported with security fixes? 2) `print([x.encode('utf-8') for x in config.sections()])`